# Why won't my javascript work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my javascript code (backslashes are for escaping):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            //datepicker
            $(\'#start\').datepicker({
                inline: true
            });
        });
</script>
```

And the relevant HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="start" id="start" class="hasDatepicker" />
```

It's essentially identical to the example code that comes with jquery and jquery ui. I'm thinking it could be that everything is appended to a variable called $content and echoed out at the end instead of simply being HTML.

I appreciate any answers to this conundrum.

I should perhaps have been more visual about how my code is set up instead of explaining it at the end. This is generally how it looks:

```
$content .= '<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            //datepicker
            $(\'#start\').datepicker({
                inline: true
            });
        });
</script>';
```

My HTML is similarly added to $content:

```
$content .= '<input type="text" name="start" id="start" class="hasDatepicker" />';
```

Comment: I always wondered what those little slanty lines were for.

Comment: Why do escape the quotes? Have you tried without it? As it is, you have a syntax error.

Comment: is this really necessary to add backslashes ?

Comment: you don't have to do that escaping.

Comment: you have a javascript problem and you haven't even checked the console for errors? I don't know what to say...

Comment: Learn JavaScript; then learn jQuery -- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html

Comment: Where does the `php` come in, are you echoing your script?

Comment: let's simplify your life and remove PHP from the picture.. check the source of the generated page (php output).

Comment: let's remove those backslashes and try again

Comment: I hope my edited question is better understood now and explains the backslashes. That said, I have tried to use the above code by itself in html without escaping the single quotes and it still does not work.

I should note that, yes, I import jquery and jqueryui. I was actually trying to use Trent Richardson's datetimepicker but had similar problem and decided to do something more basic.

Answer (score 6):

Did you try without the backslashes?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            //datepicker
            $('#start').datepicker({
                inline: true
            });
        });
</script>
```

Nothing to escape really

AND:

Do you use firebug or any other web debugging tool?

Comment: "apostrophes" means `'`, don't you mean backslash?

Comment: I was using Chrome's built-in tools, but then went to Firefox to use Firebug. I am unfamiliar with its use in debugging javascript issues.

Comment: Sounds fine, I'll watch some videos on what to do. I don't think it will help, somehow, considering I got it to work in plain HTML. It seems to be an issue with PHP, which I somehow doubt firebug will help with.

Answer (score 5):

#### Response to Updated Question

Your `$content` variable will output the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    //datepicker
    $('#start').datepicker({
      inline: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

This works as-is (assuming no problems with your page): http://jsbin.com/oxekuw/2/edit

I would encourage you to check your console output (typically accessible by hitting F12) for any message regarding `$` or `datepicker` method not being found. This would indicate their was a problem linking up either jQuery or jQuery UI.

Use the following as a template if you need to. It is also available online if you would like to do testing there: http://jsbin.com/oxekuw/3/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Datepicker</title>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.19/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        //datepicker
        $('#start').datepicker({
          inline: true
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="start" type="text" />
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Response to Original Question

You escape when single quotes are used within a string that is encapsulated by single quotes. You don't escape here though:

```
$(\'#start\'); // No-no
```

Check your console output and you'll likely see something to the effect of: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

There is a time and place for you to escape characters in your selector though. The following would be an example of when you would escape:

```
$("input[name=\"foo\"]"); // Little more sensible
```

Note, double-quotes within double-quotes. We have to distinguish our inside ones from the outside ones so that we don't terminate the string prematurely.

The better solution is to stagger your double/single quotes. If you use double quotes on the outside, use single quotes on the inside:

```
$("input[name='foo']"); // Much easier on the eyes
```

Comment: I am aware of the issues with escaping, but I see that my approach to asking the question was wrong. My newly edited question has a better representation of my code. And the comments on it describe my attempt to write the proper code in HTML only to not have it work. I've copied code verbatim from jquery's site and not have it work.

Answer (score 0):

As others noted, your code should work.

One common problem which could cause problems is that you have multiple HTML elements with that same ID ( `id="start"` ).

Answer (score -2):

Is it possible that you run the datepicker() code before the input element has been created?

Comment: This is the case, but I do not believe it would result in something simply not working as I have used jquery and javascript in the <head> before.

Comment: @KingTouchstone It's actually *not* the case, since you're wrapping your jQuery logic within `$(function(){/*...*/});`